# How to communicate with HM-19 BLE Module and scan using ultrasonic sensor

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno, arduino-ide, hm-10, arduino-ultra-sonic

I am working on my senior project for school, and part of what I need to do is use an HM-19 Bluetooth 5.0 module to connect to another Bluetooth 5.0 module and establish a master slave connection.

I can do that just fine, but when I include the code needed for my ultrasonic sensor to do scan, my commands to my HM-19 don't return anything and I can't do any of the basic functions such as finding connections. I have tested it with and without the ultrasonic sensor code and the problem occurs when I use the sensor portion of the code.

TO BE CLEAR, all I am trying to do is just have my Bluetooth 5.0 chip connect to another and do normal commands while also inputting into my serial monitor a distance when I put my hand in front. THIS IS JUST A TEST, once I get that done I will move to what I really want to do.

IT'S JUST A STARTING POINT IN A PROJECT. I have a function call for my sensor and my bluetooth chip in the void loop, that's all that is in there.

I just want to know how to fix this issue. How can I scan with my ultrasonic sensor and send commands to my Bluetooth module? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[Here are the results when the sensor is commented][1] and [here are the unsuccessful results that results in an infinite loop where I can't get to the portion of the code that returns what the chip says][2]. Lastly, although most of the links include stuff for the HM-10, the commands are basically the same for the HM-19. I'm adding more because stack overflow won't let me edit this post until there are more characters or something. I hope you have a good day/evening person reading this.

Here is my code:

```
    //  SerialIn_SerialOut_HM-10_01
//
//  Uses hardware serial to talk to the host computer and AltSoftSerial for communication with the bluetooth module
//
//  What ever is entered in the serial monitor is sent to the connected device
//  Anything received from the connected device is copied to the serial monitor
//  Does not send line endings to the HM-10
//
//  Pins
//  BT VCC to Arduino 5V out. 
//  BT GND to GND
//  Arduino D8 (SS RX) - BT TX no need voltage divider 
//  Arduino D9 (SS TX) - BT RX through a voltage divider (5v to 3.3v)
//

#include <AltSoftSerial.h>
AltSoftSerial BTserial; 
// https://www.pjrc.com/teensy/td_libs_AltSoftSerial.html


char c=' ';
boolean NL = true;
const int trigPin = 9;
const int echoPin = 10;
float duration, distance;
boolean wait_your_turn = false; //My attempt to make sure the sensor and the Bluetooth module don't interfere with each other
//if I'm sending data from the serial monitor to the bluetooth module and vice versa it switches to true and the bluetooth module 
//does its thing, so the sensor doesn't get in the way.

void setup() 
{
    pinMode(trigPin, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(echoPin, INPUT);
    Serial.begin(9600);
    Serial.print("Sketch:   ");   Serial.println(__FILE__);
    Serial.print("Uploaded: ");   Serial.println(__DATE__);
    Serial.println(" ");

    BTserial.begin(9600);  
    Serial.println("BTserial started at 9600");
}

void loop()
{
  Bluetooth();
  Sensor();
}

void Sensor(){
  if((wait_your_turn == true))
  {}

  else
  {
    Serial.println("Scanning for stuff.");
    digitalWrite(trigPin, HIGH);
    delayMicroseconds(10);
    digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW);

    duration = pulseIn(echoPin, HIGH);
    distance = (duration*.0343)/2;

    if(distance <= 20)
    {
      Serial.println(distance);
      delay(500);
    }
  }
}

void Bluetooth()
{
    if (Serial.available())
    {
     if(wait_your_turn == false)
       Serial.println("Serial is available");

      wait_your_turn = true;

     while(Serial.available()>0)
       c = Serial.read();

     Serial.write(c);

     if(c!=10&c!=13)
       BTserial.print(c);       
    }

    if (BTserial.available())
    {
      // Serial.print("We are at the bluetooth portion.");
        while(BTserial.available())
          c = BTserial.read();

        Serial.print(c);
        wait_your_turn = false;
    }
}


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dn4i0.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/s9Ifv.png
```

Comment: Here is my code:

Comment: I don't see anyplace where wait_your_turn is set to true.

Comment: wait_your_turn is set to true inside the Bluetooth() function, two lines below the the if statement if(wait_your_turn ==false) Serial.println("Serial is available.");

Comment: Then it's set to false again at the final if statement. Since the sensor and Bluetooth functions are called sequentially, I don't see the purpose in the flag.

Comment: The flag was my failed first attempt to keep the scanning and the bluetooth stuff separate. I noticed the flaw in my logic and am working on it now to see if I can get it to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, I forgot about this question. I figured it out. What I did was have 1 Arduino control the Ultrasonic sensor and send a character to the other Arduino when something was in range of the sensor. The other Arduino would then read the character and based on the character send it would perform an action. Thank you everyone who commented and have a great rest of your days.